# A sarcastic expression

Tags: expressions

When something is obvious and the other person didn’t notice a long time and then lately realised, for i.e someone come up and say

- I know I’ve broken your heart

In my mother language we go and say “Good Morning” as a sarcastic expression which means “oh yes at last you realised it but it took a good time for you to realise)

Is there any similar sarcastic way to respond in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few similar responses I am aware of. Bear in mind that some of these are particular to British English, and may not be as widely used in real, modern life as they are preserved in literature or other media. Like your expression "good morning!", they may also have a sincere meaning, so would be spoken with a sarcastic tone.

- "Eureka!" (reportedly what Archimedes shouted when he solved a problem)
- "By George, I think he's got it!" (a quote from a George Bernard Shaw play)
- "No s***, Sherlock!" (referring to Sherlock Holmes, used when someone states the obvious)
- "Ding!" (the sound of a bell, as if someone just scored a point on a game show)